# Trigger Windows Authentication Pop-up on API Call Angular / .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, angular, .net-core

I need your help, I'm using Angular and .Net core with Windows Authentication,

When I make a call from angular app to controller route withtout beeing authenticated it returns 401, that's good, but the Windows Authentication Popup doesn't show up.

If I try to access the controller route in browser, it shows me the popup. That's good,

So, how to show this popup when I make a call in Angular App when I'm not authenticated ?

My Program.cs

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("defaultPolicy",
    builder =>
    {
        builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .Build();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);


builder.Services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});


builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MoovImadDatabase"))
);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("defaultPolicy");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "use64Bit": true
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "sslPort": 44338
    }
  }
}
```

My Controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/test")]
public class TESTController: ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public TESTController(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetTESTs")]
    public List<TEST> GetTESTs()
    {
        var list = _context.TEST.ToList();
        return list;
    }

    [HttpGet("simpleTest", Name = "simpleTest")]
    [Authorize]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public string SimpleTest()
    {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

My Angular Interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(req);
        req = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

And my component TS where I made a test call

```
export class TestComponent {
    message: string | null = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    loginWithWindowsAuth() {
        this.http.get<any>('https://localhost:44338/api/test/simpleTest').subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.message = data.message;
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
                this.message = null;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help,

Regards